How to add route prefix to all routes using the router from the http package?
I'm constructing my API router inside a function
package api

import "net/http"

func New() http.Handler {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("GET /ping", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    })

    // other routes go here...

    return mux
}

and I want every route to have the route prefix /api. Do I have to create a subrouter for this like so?
// ...

apiRouter := http.NewServeMux()

// let the apiRouter instance handle all routes now
apiRouter.HandleFunc("GET /ping", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
})

mux.Handle("/api/", http.StripPrefix("/api", apiRouter))

// ...

so I'm basically a new router instance inside the mux instance. But is there a simpler way to achieve this? This approach feels weird because I have to nest an additional router instance.

Does this answer your question? Go net/http routes

@erik258 I'm not sure, this shounds like "yes, you have to create a subrouter for this"

weird is a matter of opinion. But yes, you have to create a subrouter to get the behavior you want, unless you want to explicitly prepend it to each route path (you don't, of course).  and I would argue it makes sense, because it provides a layer that maps /api  to the locations you want to define without that component of the path
